# javascript how to crud a key value pair array into a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, crud, key-value

I need to store a key value array in a field like this:

```
<input type="text" id="test" >{key1="a"}{key2="b"}</input>
```

How can I read and update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input tag is invalid; it needs to be self-closing.

That said, I would store the data as a data-* attribute with JSON inside:

```
<input data-val='{ "key1": "a", "key2": "b"}' type="text" id="test" />
```

From there you can read the value, parse it, update it, stringify it back, and update the attribute.

---

Something like this should get you started, just note that some of it will break in older browsers, so you may have to shim things like `JSON.parse/stringify`.  And come to think of it, `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` are not supported in IE7.  I'm not sure what the workaround is for those browsers.

```
var inp = document.getElementById('test');
var obj = JSON.parse(inp.getAttribute('data-val'));

console.log(obj);

obj.key1 = "updated";
obj.key3 = "foo";

inp.setAttribute('data-val', JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log("updated", inp.getAttribute('data-val'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LH9eN/)

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON has to use double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Double quotes makes sense as value can potentially have `'` in it.